# Image next to text

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, timeline

I've [this code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGzOLY) and I need to have the picture on the same line as Timeline headline.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="page-header">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/J1d-4ze1atTh6BbMXh34eK_4fEttHBlztlWcgjKbzzd79zQYCqkLxw07Gh7oRdJrZAybyTG3acXKn7QHh3S54bgZ7awV5YQm6XZiTp_OHJq1f3a0aoOHusbbWq2kc6oAmg" width="100px" height="124px" class="img-thumbnail">
    <h1 id="timeline">Timeline</h1>
</div>
....
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPgbYZ

**HTML**

```
 <div class="page-header">
        <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/J1d-4ze1atTh6BbMXh34eK_4fEttHBlztlWcgjKbzzd79zQYCqkLxw07Gh7oRdJrZAybyTG3acXKn7QHh3S54bgZ7awV5YQm6XZiTp_OHJq1f3a0aoOHusbbWq2kc6oAmg" width="100px" height="124px" class="img-thumbnail">
        <span id="timeline" class="heading-text">Timeline</span>
    </div>
```

CSS: (added)

```
.heading-text{
  margin-left:10px;
  font-size:38px;
  vertical-align:bottom;
}
```